# Print out the array in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have 2 classes in java to calculate the mortgage and monthly payment:

The first one is:

```
public class Loan {

    private double mortgageAmount;
    private double annualInterestRate;
    private int amortizationPeriod;

    //Setter and getter here
    public Loan(double mortgageAmount, double annualInterestRate, int amortizationPeriod) {
        super();
        this.mortgageAmount = mortgageAmount;
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
        this.amortizationPeriod = amortizationPeriod;
        getMonthlyPayment();
        getLoanScheduleArray();
    }

    public double getMonthlyPayment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double monthlyPayment;
        monthlyPayment = roundTo2Decimal(mortgageAmount * (Math.pow((1 + (annualInterestRate) / 200), (double) 1 / 6) - 1)
                / (1 - Math.pow(Math.pow((1 + (annualInterestRate) / 200), (double) 1 / 6), -12 * amortizationPeriod)));

        return monthlyPayment;
    }

    public Loan() {
        super();
    }

    public LoanSchedule[] getLoanScheduleArray() {
        LoanSchedule[] loanScheduleArray = new LoanSchedule[amortizationPeriod * 12];
        double remainingBalance = mortgageAmount;

        for (int index = 0; index < (amortizationPeriod * 12); index++) {

            int paymentNumber = index + 1;

            if (paymentNumber < amortizationPeriod * 12) {

                double monthlyPercentageRate = (Math.pow(1 + annualInterestRate / 200, (double) 1 / 6) - 1);
                double interestPaid = roundTo2Decimal(remainingBalance * monthlyPercentageRate);
                double principalPaid = roundTo2Decimal(getMonthlyPayment() - interestPaid);
                remainingBalance = roundTo2Decimal(remainingBalance - principalPaid);
                LoanSchedule loanSchedule = new LoanSchedule();
                loanSchedule.setPaymentNumber(paymentNumber);
                loanSchedule.setInterestPaid(interestPaid);
                loanSchedule.setPrincipalPaid(principalPaid);
                loanSchedule.setRemainingBalance(remainingBalance);
                loanScheduleArray[index] = loanSchedule;
            }

        }
        return loanScheduleArray;
    }
}
```

And the 2nd one is

```
public class LoanSchedule {

    //getter and setter here
    public LoanSchedule(int paymentNumber, double interestPaid, double principalPaid, double remainingBlance) {
        super();
    }

    public LoanSchedule() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Now I want to print out the interest paid, principal paid and remaining balance for every month, so I have these code in java servlet, but it doesn't print anything in the array. Where am I going wrong?

```
for (int index = 0; index < (intAmortizationPeriod * 12); index++) {
    LoanSchedule loanSchedule = loanScheduleArray[index];
    response.getWriter().println(loanSchedule);
}
```

This is my servlet code:

```
public class LoanServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoanServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        String mortgageAmount = request.getParameter("mortgageAmount");
        String annualInterestRate = request.getParameter("annualInterestRate");
        String amortizationPeriod = request.getParameter("amortizationPeriod");

        double dbMortgageAmount = Double.parseDouble(mortgageAmount);
        double dbAnnualInterestRate = Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRate);
        int intAmortizationPeriod = Integer.parseInt(amortizationPeriod);

        int errorCount = 0;
        StringBuffer errors = new StringBuffer("Please fix the following issue(s):");
        errors.append("<ul class=\"bg-danger\">");
        if (mortgageAmount.isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("<li>Mortgage amount is required.</li>");
            errorCount++;
        }

        if (annualInterestRate.isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("<li>Annual interes trate is required.</li>");
            errorCount++;
        }

        if (amortizationPeriod.isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("<li>Amortization period is required.</li>");
            errorCount++;
        }

        errors.append("</ul>");
        if (errorCount == 0) {
            //double taxableIncome = Double.parseDouble( taxableIncomeString );
            Loan loanbean = new Loan(dbMortgageAmount, dbAnnualInterestRate, intAmortizationPeriod);
            loanbean.getMonthlyPayment();

            LoanSchedule[] loanScheduleArray = loanbean.getLoanScheduleArray();

            String htmlResponseText = "Your monthly payment is <strong>" + loanbean.getMonthlyPayment() + "</strong>.";
            response.getWriter().println(htmlResponseText);

            for (int index = 0; index < (intAmortizationPeriod * 12); index++) {
                LoanSchedule loanSchedule = loanScheduleArray[index];
                response.getWriter().println(loanSchedule.toString());
            }

        } else {
            response.getWriter().println(errors.toString());
        }
    }

    private void println(Object setPaymentNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `intAmortizationPeriod` is set? Print that, too, just to make sure.

Comment: It doesn't print *anything*?

Comment: I meant it doesn't print anything in the array. I got some thing look like "packagename.LoanSchedule@61f4e55b" when I run html file for this servlet.

Comment: It appears that your loanSchedule class does not have a valid "toString" method.  Implement that and you will see better results.

Comment: I just post the whole servlet class in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a toString method to LoanSchedule

```
public String toString() {
   return "paymentNumber=" + paymentNumber + ","
                + " interestPaid=" 
                + interestPaid + ", principalPaid=" + 
                principalPaid+ ", remainingBlance="
                + remainingBlance;
    }
```

and update the code in servlet as below

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("<table>");
    for (int index = 0; index < (intAmortizationPeriod * 12); index++) {

        LoanSchedule loanSchedule = loanScheduleArray[index];
        sb.append("<tr><td>");
        sb.append(loanSchedule.toString());
        sb.append("</td></tr>");
    }
    sb.append("</table>");
    response.getWriter().println(sb.toString());

You can still format the toString method as needed
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But if I print the array like this:

for (int index = 0;index < (intAmortizationPeriod * 12 ); index++) {
            LoanSchedule loanSchedule = loanScheduleArray[index];
            response.getWriter().println(loanSchedule.getPaymentNumber());
 response.getWriter().println(loanSchedule.getInterestPaid());
 response.getWriter().println(loanSchedule.getPrincipalPaid());         response.getWriter().println(loanSchedule.getRemainingBalance());
        }
Is that anyway to put those result into the html table??

Comment: Its better to build a string containing the html text instead of using the response.getWriter().println() multiple times. So in this loop try building the html text and then finally pass it to response.getWriter().println()

Answer (score 0):

Why not run `loanScheduleArray.size()` amount of time (inside the for loop)?

Comment: Actually, It printed something for me, but that's not the value in the array. It' look like "packagename.LoanSchedule@61f4e55b"

Comment: @GiangNguyen Use System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(loanScheduleArray));

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I should have the code like this in my servlet class:

```
for (int index = 0;index < (intAmortizationPeriod * 12 ); index++) {
            LoanSchedule loanSchedule = loanScheduleArray[index];
            response.getWriter().println(loanSchedule.getPaymentNumber());
            response.getWriter().println(loanSchedule.getInterestPaid());
            response.getWriter().println(loanSchedule.getPrincipalPaid());
            response.getWriter().println(loanSchedule.getRemainingBalance());
        }
```

But the result is displayed too bad. How can I arrange it in to the table for better look??

Comment: Start learning JSP. It's much more suited for dynamically generating HTML output than a servlet.